# compare dates in C++

Tags: c++, datetime

i have a file, 'date.txt' which has date in it. Like,
Mon Oct 13 09:37:08 2009.

Now i want to compare this date with system date. How can i compare dates in C++.?

I used this code to get the contents from the file 'date.txt'

```
    string date;
    while ( inDateFile >>date) //inDateFile is an ifstream object 
           cout<<date<<endl;
```

And this code to get system date,

```
  time_t timer;
  struct tm *tblock;
  timer = time(NULL);
  tblock = localtime(&timer);
  string str = asctime(tblock);
```

Now how can i compare these two dates.?

Comment: There isn't enough data here to answer the question.  What is the type of 'date' in the first code snippet?

Comment: date is a string data type. I'm just reading contents of the file in string and displaying them

Comment: this is not an answer per se, just a comment: how is the region going to affect your text that you read in or is it irrelevant here? Seems to me that this whole requirement is a bit fragile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse values, use [`std::mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) function to get `time_t` and now use [`std::difftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/difftime) to get the difference.

Answer (score 2):

We use boost [date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time.html) for reading dates from strings and then comparing them. It works very well in our experience.

Answer (score 1):

convert the date string to a numeric time value (32 or 64 bits), aka, make time, then compare to the system time which time(NULL) returned.

Comment: Yeah, don't bother converting the current date to a string.  It won't give you much.  Besides storing the data.txt info as "time" will make it easier to manipulate later.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just parse the string in your file you need to split up the string in the resp values, you also probably need to check what country region to take that into account since different regions have different order/month names etc. You could make that configurable in which order the different tokens appear in your text.

One way to solve this is by for instance take your string 'date' and then use the template [Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) from boost (or if you want to do it the C way call the strtok() function) to split up the string into substrings depending on delimiters. After that it is easy to convert the input.

Another maybe simpler way is when you read from the file instead of reading the whole string read up to a delimiter e.g. ',' then read again - you can use inDateFile.getline() for that.

Answer (score -2):

http://datetime.perl.org/index.cgi?FAQBasicUsage

You will have to convert your date from txt file to tm structre before you compare.

Comment: @iamiPhone , i think solution is expected in c++